# Localized string values for the size strings KB, MB, GB etc.?

Tags: winapi, localization

Where is this strins resources is stored on the Windows? 
I need to show size corectly on native language of installed Windows.

Comment: What makes you think those strings are stored in resources you can access? You should be localizing your own strings, not using strings from the OS.

Comment: CLDR contains information you need. Each locale has a rule how to use K, M, G, etc and then CLDR contains the localized names of each factor both long and short names. Keep in mind that some language do not work by thousands but for example by 10 000's (Japanese)

Comment: @Jaska thanks for the info, I will read about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with disk quota library which is available since Windows XP:

```
function FindStringResourceEx(AInstance: HINST; AStringID: UINT; ALangID: UINT): PWideChar;
var
  Res: HRSRC;
  LoadedRes: HGLOBAL;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := nil;
  Res := FindResourceEx(AInstance, RT_STRING, MAKEINTRESOURCE(AStringID div 16 + 1), ALangID);
  if Res <> 0 then begin
    LoadedRes := LoadResource(AInstance, Res);
    if LoadedRes <> 0 then
    try
      Result := PChar(LockResource(LoadedRes));
      if Assigned(Result) then
      try
        for I := 0 to (AStringID and 15) - 1 do
          Inc(Result, PWord(Result)^ + 1);
      finally
        UnlockResource(THandle(Result));
      end;
    finally
      FreeResource(LoadedRes);
    end;
  end;
end;

function GetSizeStrings(out sBytes, sKB, sMB, sGB, sTB, sPB, sEB: string): Boolean;
var
  hLib: HMODULE;
  sRes: string;
  I: Integer;
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  Result := False;
  hLib := LoadLibrary('dskquoui.dll');
  if hLib > 0 then
  try
    SL := TStringList.Create;
    try
      sRes := FindStringResourceEx(hLib, 14472, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL));
      Result := sRes <> '';
      if Result then begin
        sRes := sRes.Remove(0, 1);
        I := sRes.IndexOf(#$B);
        if I > -1 then
          sRes := sRes.Remove(I);
        SL.Delimiter := #2;
        SL.DelimitedText := sRes;
        sBytes := SL[0]; // bytes
        sKB    := SL[1]; // KB
        sMB    := SL[2]; // MB
        sGB    := SL[3]; // GB
        sTB    := SL[4]; // TB
        sPB    := SL[5]; // PB
        sEB    := SL[6]; // EB
      end;
    finally
      SL.Free;
    end;
  finally
    FreeLibrary(hLib);
  end;
  if not Result then begin
    sBytes := 'bytes';
    sKB    := 'KB';
    sMB    := 'MB';
    sGB    := 'GB';
    sTB    := 'TB';
    sPB    := 'PB';
    sEB    := 'EB';
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are very specific to the application that is using it. There are no generic string resouce in windows that an application can use. Of course you can write a program to search the resource in the windows folder to see which resource dll has the string that you are looking for and then use that resource dll in your application, but that is unadvisable. The reason being that, any new update of the windows that brings in resource dll changes can break your application.

As the other poster advises, you are better of writing your own resource dll and localize it in the languages that you want to support your application.